# when i try to compile it says "h" is not initialized. however it works sometimes depending on what i do below. whats am i not getting here?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //get height
    int h;
    do
    {
        get_int("Height: ");

    } while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    //
    for (int y = 7 - h; y > 0; y--)
    {
        if (y < 0)
            printf("#  #");
        else
            printf(" ");
    }

    for (int x = 0; h > x; x++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}
```

I have been working on this all day and I am just not getting it. sometimes when I check, my code is identical to the lesson yet it won't work. I am not sure if it is my spacing or what. or I'll fix an error and keep working only for it to come back after I had not even touched that area since I got it working. feeling completely lost.

Comment: It seems you mean h = get_int("Height: "); instead of get_int("Height: ");

Comment: The value of an uninitialized variable is indeterminate. Did you mean to assign the result of the `get_int("Height: ")` call to `h`?

Comment: @asanaya91 Also this if statement     if( y< 0)
        printf("#  #"); does not make a sense. y can not be less than zero within the for loop.

Comment: @asanaya91 I think the question should be closed because the presented program does not make any sense.

Comment: @FredLarson yes thats what i want. do i have something out of order?

Comment: Then you should actually assign the result of `get_int("Height: ")` to `h`. Right now, the value just goes unused and `h` remains uninitialized. See @chqrlie's answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow youre right about y<0 so i changed it to 1 now. but of course it doesnt make sense thats why im here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because `h` is uninitialized and you never store the return value of `get_int("Height: ")` into it.

The value of `h` is undefined, so it can be different for different runs of your program, thus explaining the observed behavior. The fix is easy: just write `h = get_int("Height: ");` in the `do`/`while` loop.

Here is a modified value:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int h;

    do  {
        h = get_int("Height: ");

    } while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    for (int y = 7 - h; y > 0; y--) {
        if (y < 0)
            printf("#  #");
        else
            printf(" ");
    }

    for (int x = 0; h > x; x++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read my comments to the question.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I did, and I agree with your assessment. I wrote an answer so the OP understands the problem leading to undefined behavior. There are other problems but I am not even sure what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: thanks this worked. i thought of putting the `h=` before but i could swear that messed it up before when i tried it with `int h;` at the top